# aiohttp request times out when using a proxy, but is fine when i run without a proxy

Tags: request, timeout, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am attempting to scrape a site using a proxy in aiohttp with asyncio but whenever I run the code with a proxy it times out. I have removed the proxy from the code because it is a DC proxy. Does anyone know why my request would be timing out? It does work when I run without a proxy.
code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import random

async def fetch(session,):
    UAList = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
              'Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
              'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
              'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
              'Chrome/83.0.4103.97 '
              'Safari/537.36',
              'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
              'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
              'Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36', ]
    # chooses a random User Agent(From the list above) for the header
    rUserAgent = random.choice(UAList)
    rHeader = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
                  'application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        'cookie': 'cookie',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': rUserAgent
    }


    proxy = 'http://'
    url = 'http://www.yeezysupply.com/product/GY7657'
    async with session.get(url=url,allow_redirects=False,headers=rHeader,proxy=proxy) as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.text()


async def main():
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session)
        print(html)


policy = asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(policy)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score -1):

As I cannot tell from the post, your `proxy` should have the following structure:
`http://username:password@proxy_url:proxy_port` or `http://proxy_url:_proxy_port`

Please try to redefine your `main()` like this:

```
async def main():
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn, timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout()) as session:
        html = await fetch(session)
        print(html)
```

During my tests, I found that the `assert resp.status == 200` would fail, if the toGet-URL was set to `http://` instead of `https://` as using `http://` would result in a redirect (status code 301) for me.